# Nuxt importing root in page's folders when using SSG

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

My **pages** folder is structured as follows:

[image: Pages folder structure]

**/index.vue (root)**

```
<template>
  <div class="red"></div>
</template>

<style>
    .red {
        background-color: red;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

**/folder.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
    <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  .yellow {
      background-color: rgb(229, 255, 0);
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

**/folder/Index.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</template>

<style>
  .blue {
      background-color: rgb(23, 43, 136);
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

When i call localhost i get the correct index.vue page:

[image: picture of index.vue]

Same applies for calling localhost/folder

[image: picture of folder/index.vue]

But when i execute `npm run generate` and go to the example.com/folder route i get the red square from the index:

[image]

Below is a picture executing it on localhost:

[image]

The red class is imported when the code is created for some reason. My `nuxt.config` doesn't have anything besides the `devtools` set to `false` and this project was setup using only `npx nuxi@latest init my-app` (Nuxt is the latest 3.5.2 version)

Am i missing something related to the config to deploy on SSR? Seems like both index.vue are having a conflict and both are being imported while only `folder/index.vue` should have been.

I would appreciate any help to solve this matter.